# How to calculate homotopic groups : $\pi_n(Z)$ and $\pi_n(S^0)$ .

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

While doing an exercise, I need to show that $Z$ and $S^0$ are not homotopically equivalent. To do so, I'd like to show that $\pi_n(Z) \neq \pi_n(S^0)$ for some $n$. But I can't figure out if to consider $\pi_0(.)$ or $\pi_n(.)$ since I can't find what it would give for $Z$. 
I hope the question is clear !
thanks

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what is $Z$ and what is $S^0$.

Comment: Sorry about that, $S^0$ is the 0-sphere, so basically two points, and $Z$ are the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S^0 = \{-1, 1\}$, i.e. a disjoint union of two points. Similarly (assuming the discrete topology...), $\mathbb{Z}$ is a disjoint union of infinitely many points.

Now the higher homotopy groups of a point are all trivial (why? You should hopefully be able to verify this), so $\pi_n(S^0) = 0 = \pi_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for $n > 0$. Thus the only other place to look is $n = 0$.

At this point, remember what one reasonable interpretation of $\pi_0$ is, and think about my first paragraph...

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense ! but I am not sure, is $\pi_0(Z)$ the cyclic group of order 2 ?

Comment: Well, $\pi_0$ is not a group, but a pointed set.

Comment: Uuum ok. I am not sure I understood well. $\pi_0(X)$ gives the arc-connected components of $X$ right ?

Comment: Correct. So how many of those are there for $\mathbb{Z}$?